# Object reference not set in

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public static Boolean ValidateUser(string struser, string strpass)
{
    // Establish connection information
    SqlConnection conn_string = new   SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=137.145.169.3;Initial Catalog=SICI4266;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SICI4266G3;Password=*******"].ConnectionString);
    // Establish SQL command
    SqlCommand sql_comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(userID) FROM HIEPA.HIEPA_USERS where UserName = @usuario and UserPassword = @contrasena ; ", conn_string);
    // Provide Parameter values
    sql_comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", struser);
    sql_comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", strpass);
    // Open the connection
    conn_string.Open();
    // Execute the SQL command and assign the resulting value to an integer variable
    Int32 intUserCount = Convert.ToInt32(sql_comm.ExecuteScalar());
    // Close the connection
    conn_string.Close();
    // Evaluate the integer variable content; greater than cero is a valid combination
    if (intUserCount == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

can somebody tell me why this error is prompted?

[image]

Comment: You have to put the name of the connection string in the braces, not the connection string itself. Or you use `SqlConnection conn_string = new   SqlConnection("Data Source=137.145.169.3;Initial Catalog=SICI4266;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SICI4266G3;Password=*******"");` Replace the wildcards with the password of course

Comment: Read [What is a NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/), [learn how to debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), and [stop showing pictures of errors](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: I believe @schlonzo answered correctly. The rest of your code looks ok. I would use a using(){} instead though. Also, it's probably best not to include any real User IDs, or IP Addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This expression from the line highlighted in red in the exception results is `null`:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=137.145.169.3;Initial Catalog=SICI4266;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SICI4266G3;Password=*******"]
```

It's null because the `Connection[]` property expects the **name** of a string, and not the full string. It's trying lookup the string in a collection, doesn't find that big long blob of text, and so returns `null`.

Given the above, you then try to the reference the `.Connection` string property of a `null` reference. It's as if you had done this:

```
null.ConnectionString;
```

Either change that code to use the name of the connection string as listed in the `web.config` file, or since you have the whole string there already just give that string directly to the `SqlConnection()` constructor. Either way, that code should be cleaned up some:

```
//comments should focus on "why", rather than "what"
public static Boolean ValidateUser(string struser, string strpass)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn string name"].ConnectionString))
    using (var sql_comm = new SqlCommand(""SELECT count(userID) FROM HIEPA.HIEPA_USERS where UserName = @usuario and UserPassword = @contrasena ; ", conn))
    {
        //Don't use AddWithValue(). It forces ADO.Net to guess about parameter types.
        //Use exact column types and lengths instead
        sql_comm.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = struser;
        //Dear God, please tell me you're not using a plain-text password? That's a HUGE mistake!
        sql_comm.Parameters.Add("@contrasena", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 180).Value = strpass;

        conn.Open();
        return (1 == (int)sql_comm.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your web.config, it means your connection string name is "Default"

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=137.145.169.3;Initial Catalog=SICI4266;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SICI4266G3;Password=*******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings>
```

So, the correct way to add connection string in your code is-

```
SqlConnection conn_string = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString);
```